# Out of bounds error with simple sort program using threading library

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to do two sorts. Bubble sort and insertion sort to practice using multi threading in python. Everything is fine when running each thread on their own but when I run the two threads one after the other the bubble sort is getting a list out of bounds error. This is confusing me because it works on its own but does not want to work with the other thread running simultaneously.

```
Error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 21, in bubbleSortArray
    if arr[x] < arr[y]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
import threading
from tqdm import tqdm
import random
    
def insertionSortArray(arr):

    # Simple Insertion sort to start out
 
    for x in tqdm(range(len(arr))):
        for y in range(x):
            if arr[x] < arr[y]:
                arr.insert(y, arr[x])
                del arr[x + 1]
                break
    print(arr)

def bubbleSortArray(arr):

    # Simple Bubble sort to start out
    
    for x in tqdm(range(len(arr))):
        for y in range(len(arr)):
            if arr[x] < arr[y]:
                temp = arr[x]
                arr[x] = arr[y]
                arr[y] = temp
    print(arr)
    
def generateArray(size):
    
    return [random.randrange(0, 10000) for x in range(size)]
    
#generating the array for the thread functions

array = generateArray(10000)
   
bubble = threading.Thread(target = bubbleSortArray, args=[array])
insertion = threading.Thread(target = insertionSortArray, args=[array])
    
bubble.start()
insertion.start()
```

Comment: You are passing a reference to the same array to both threads. Pass a copy.

Comment: @MarkTolonen This is not the issue. Even if it was the same array being passed it would be doing a sort on a sorted array. The error that is showing up is an array out of bounds error. I did a test also and it did not work. Thank you for your time commenting though.

Comment: Remember they are being acted on in parallel and insertionSortArray is inserting and deleting sections of the array.

Comment: I reproduced the error with your code and added `args=[array.copy()]` as the threading argument and it fixed it.  You *definitely* do not want to sort the same array in parallel.

Comment: The `tqdm` progress bars don't work too well in parallel either.  They can't both update the same console line and end up scrolling.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ah yes, I apologize for my ignorance...

i forgot that the size of the array is being directly manipulated with the insertion sort that I coded...

Thank you for your input, My issue has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to not pass the same array object to both threads.  Make a copy.

Also use the `position` argument to `tqdm` to work with threads.

```
import threading
import random
import time

import tqdm

def insertionSortArray(arr):
    # Simple Insertion sort to start out
    with tqdm.tqdm(desc=f'InsertionSort', total=len(arr), position=1) as bar:
        for x in range(len(arr)):
            for y in range(x):
                if arr[x] < arr[y]:
                    arr.insert(y, arr[x])
                    del arr[x + 1]
                    break
            bar.update(1)

def bubbleSortArray(arr):
    # Simple Bubble sort to start out
    with tqdm.tqdm(desc=f'BubbleSort   ', total=len(arr), position=0) as bar:
        for x in range(len(arr)):
            for y in range(len(arr)):
                if arr[x] < arr[y]:
                    temp = arr[x]
                    arr[x] = arr[y]
                    arr[y] = temp
            bar.update(1)
    
def generateArray(size):
    return [random.randrange(0, 10000) for x in range(size)]

#generating the array for the thread functions
array1 = generateArray(10000)
array2 = array1.copy() # Make a copy of the random list.

bubble = threading.Thread(target = bubbleSortArray, args=[array1])
insertion = threading.Thread(target = insertionSortArray, args=[array2])
bubble.start()
insertion.start()

bubble.join()
insertion.join()

# Check results
assert array1 == sorted(array1)
assert array1 == array2
```

Output:

```
InsertionSort: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10000/10000 [00:02<00:00, 4007.63it/s]
BubbleSort   : 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10000/10000 [00:07<00:00, 1426.69it/s]
```

If `.copy()` is removed:

```
C:\>py test.py
InsertionSort:   0%|                                                                         | 0/10000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Exception in thread Thread-1:                                                                 | 0/10000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
InsertionSort:  43%|█████████████████████████▍                                 | 4314/10000 [00:00<00:00, 42714.45it/s]    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\test.py", line 29, in bubbleSortArray
    if arr[x] < arr[y]:
IndexError: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 51, in <module>
    assert array1 == sorted(array1)
AssertionError
```

Comment: I was looking through your code and i was wondering if you could explain what is going on inside of the braces inside of the fstring with the :.0%. I was assuming that this is a way to truncate the percentage but have not seen this syntax before.

Comment: @mamaluigie In `f''{x:.0%}'` the `%` formats `x` as a floating point percentage (multiplies by 100 and adds a percent sign).  `.0` is rounding the floating point value to zero places after the decimal.  See [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)